# in JetPack Compose. I want to see 3 lines and then see the whole text on click

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Text(
text = "my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,",
fontSize = 16.sp
)

I want to see 3 dots in the end

Answer (score 0):

```
var showMore = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            val text = "this is a very long text" 

            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(100))
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = null
                    ) { showMore.value = !showMore.value }) {

                    if (showMore.value) {
                        Text(text = text)
                    } else {
                        Text(text = text, maxLines = 3, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use the overflow, it will not exceeds the width of its container,

```
Text(
    text = "long text goes here ,long text goes here ,long text goes here ,long text goes here ,long text goes here ,",
    fontSize = 16.sp,
    maxLines = 1, // Limit to one line
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis // Display ellipsis when the text overflows
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick answer.

```
var isTextExpand by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
Text(
     text = "my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,",
     fontSize = 16.sp,
     maxLines = when (isTextExpand) {
              false -> 3
              else -> Int.MAX_VALUE
     },
     overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
     modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
              isTextExpand = !isTextExpand
     })
)
```

**Outputs**

[image: preview]

edit:
BTW To use by operator, make sure you have imported both of

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set maxline at onClick.

```
var maxline by remember {
        mutableStateOf(3)
    }
    Text(text = "my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,my very long text,",
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            maxLines = maxline,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                maxline = Int.MIN_VALUE
            }
    )
```